# how do I invoke action with the given object in struts 2 and jsp?

Tags: jsp, struts2, jsp-tags

On one page I have a list of Destinations (read cities). When I click on one, I need to navigate to an action/result pair that would spit out the Destination details.

(I'm using struts 2)

Menu.jsp:

```
 <s:iterator value="destinations">
         <li> <s:property value="name" /> </li>
 </s:iterator>
```

where destinations is a Set in MenuAction.java.

Destination.jsp

```
Name: <s:property value="destination.name" />
```

where destination is a property in DestinationAction.java.

How do I wrap the destinations on Menu.jsp so that I can pass on the `Destination` object from **Menu.jsp** to `DestinationActio`n ?

Comment: i believe you need to pass the destination name/id to your `DestinationAction` so you can fetch the destination information and display it?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Sure, that would work too. When I display the destination on Menu page, I retrieve "all destination objects" from DAO.

Comment: i am not sure why you fetching the destination object to show the menu since that can work by just fetching few property like name and id rest can be fetch in main destination call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Umesh's comments, this is what I ended up using:

```
<ul>
         <s:iterator value="destinations">
            <li>
                <s:url action="Destination" var="urlTag">
                <s:param name="id"> <s:property value="id" /> </s:param>
                </s:url>
                <a href="<s:property value="#urlTag" />" > 
                    <s:property value="name" /> 
                </a> 
            </li>
         </s:iterator>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the  `destination` object from JSP to Action, pass only the `name` property ( and other properties according to your need). In `Menu.jsp` use links like this:

```
<s:iterator value="destinations">
     <li> 
          <a href='DestinationAction.action?destination.name=<s:property value="name" />' > 
             <s:property value="name" /> 
         </a> 
     </li>
</s:iterator>
```